# Colorbox, can't control size of Youtube Video... too small

Tags: youtube, colorbox

I'm [setting up colorbox here](http://jesseaknight.com/wbc/)
(click expand-all, then the 2nd link)
but the YouTube video I'm embedding in colorbox show up the wrong size. "Close" is also in an odd location.
photo showing the problem: i.stack.imgur.com/of8X4.png

It should be a 720p video, and open quite large.
I've tried changing this line in the script, but it has no effect:

```
    $(".youtube").colorbox({iframe:true, innerWidth:960, innerHeight:720});
```

Do I need to give it a size in the html?

```
<li><a class='youtube' href="http://www.youtube.com/embed/hvHB5RvdorU?rel=0&amp;wmode=transparent">Forming System Assembly Video</a></li>
```

There's a chance the expanding list is stepping on it Colorbox, [I got the code from here](http://jasalguero.com/ledld/development/web/expandable-list/). It's jQuery based.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You forgot to include the colorbox CSS file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorbox.css" />
```

Note that when you [download colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox), the zip file will include 5 examples.  Each example has a different style of colorbox defined in the colorbox.css file (located in the example's folder, e.g., "Example 1/colorbox.css").  Choose your flavor and copy the corresponding colorbox.css file into your css directory.